# How do you show that every non-constant real valued harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a zero? What about $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $\{0\}$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

How do you show that every non-constant real valued harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a zero? What about $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0):

If it is non-constant, then it can't be either bounded from above or from below.
You can use the [short proof from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville's_theorem). In particular, it must have a zero.

On $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ you can take $1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.